# Dealing with files and folders with space in data.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, space

If I try to load images/folders with spaces, I get this error.

```
message: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\\Users\\John\\ReactProjects\\my-site\\frontend\\build\\index.html'"
```

Though it works if I delete spaces but I am not satisfied with this solution.

[image]

My project hierarchy

[image: project hierarchy]

Edit 1 :

```
products: [
  {
    name: "Gotham",
    category: "NY",
    image: "/images/Homepage and Store/Gotham.jpg",
    countInStock: 5,
  },
...
]

{products.map((product, index) => (
<img
  className="absolute object-contain w-full h-full"
  src={product.image}
  alt={product.name}
/>
)}
```

server.js

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "build")));
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to put `%20` in the image url in the code. You can freely put there spaces and the browser while requesting the resource will replace them with `%20`.

URL in the code:

```
"images/Homepage and Store/Gotham.jpg"
```

Browser request:

```
images/Homepage%20and%20Store/Gotham.jpg
```

Comment: Yeah, I omit to say that I tried this as well and it didn't work, see edit

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know why it works like that. Would you mind sharing the full code, it might help the others to make up a solution for your problem.

Comment: yeah, thanks for your time, see edit 1. Actually it returns 
message: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\\Users\\John\\ReactProjects\\my-site\\frontend\\build\\index.html'" when I leave spaces